# Right way to write commands and parameters

Tags: macros, minted

I was about to ask a question related to what I thought was a bug in the `minted` package, but I now realise that I'm to blame for not defining commands correctly. I've always believed it was as simple as:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{do some stuff with parameter #1}
```

But I was wrong: the following shorthands I tried to write duplicate the `#` character, and things are even worse if I decide to use `%`, which gets parsed as a LaTeX comment rather than a modulo operator.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand{\shellinline}[1]{\mintinline{shell}{#1}}
\newcommand{\pythoninline}[1]{{\mintinline{shell}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is a ``shell comment'' with mintinline: \mintinline{shell}{# comment} % prints # comment

\noindent This is a ``shell comment'' with my command: \shellinline{# comment} % prints ## comment

\noindent This is a ``python comment'' with mintinline: \mintinline{python}{# comment} % prints # comment

\noindent This is a ``python comment'' with my command: \pythoninline{# comment} % prints ## comment

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong, and what is the right way to write these commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use verbatim-like commands in the argument or definition of another command.

If you have

```
\mycommand{zzz % zzz}
```

Then the `%` is already seen as a comment (and so the closing `}` is not seen at all) so `zzz % zzz` is never passed to the inner minted command.

Such commands need to change the parsing rules *before* grabbing the argument.

The `minted` package provides a `\newmintinline` command to define shortcut commands that call `\mintedinline` with specific options.

Comment: It's actually `\newmintinline` (not `\newmintedinline`) but thanks, this command solved my problem. I'm not sure what to do in a more general setting where I cannot rely on that environment's help, but minted is what actually matters to me at the moment, so I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre typo fixed, sorry

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre virtually all packages that provide verbatim like commands provide such a definition form to hide the command they define, fancyverb, listings, etc

Answer (score 1):

David Carlisle already explained that comments like `\mintinline` change the parsing-rules before grabbing their arguments and that you can use `\newmintinline`.

In your special case, however, you can define `\shellinline` and `\pythoninline` in a way where the argument whose parsing-rules are to be changed is grabbed by the `\mintinline`-command rather than by your user-defined command:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand{\shellinline}{\mintinline{shell}}
\MakeRobust\shellinline
\newcommand{\pythoninline}{\mintinline{python}}
\MakeRobust\pythoninline

\begin{document}

\noindent This is a ``shell comment'' with mintinline: \mintinline{shell}{# comment} % prints # comment

\noindent This is a ``shell comment'' with my command: \shellinline{# comment} % prints # comment

\noindent This is a ``python comment'' with mintinline: \mintinline{python}{# comment} % prints # comment

\noindent This is a ``python comment'' with my command: \pythoninline{# comment} % prints # comment

\noindent This is a ``shell comment'' with mintinline: \mintinline{shell}{% comment} % prints % comment

\noindent This is a ``shell comment'' with my command: \shellinline{% comment} % prints % comment

\noindent This is a ``python comment'' with mintinline: \mintinline{python}{% comment} % prints % comment

\noindent This is a ``python comment'' with my command: \pythoninline{% comment} % prints % comment

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, I had decided not to mention that,  teaching people it's safe to stand on a cliff edge:-) +1 for being braver than me though

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Cliff edge, yes. :-) Besides this my answer covers only the very special case where the argument is just grabbed and processed by `\mintinline`. Cases of pre-processing/duplicating/adding things to the argument before passing things to `\mintinline` are not covered by my answer while - afaik - using `\newmintinline` such things can be done.|| Me being braver?? This reminds me of a dialogue in Star Trek -- **Clingon General Martok:** _You are either very brave, or very stupid, Ferengi!_ **Ferengi Nog:** _Probably a little of both._